# linearlayout + button in linearlayout works fine but button + linearlayout don't

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I want to change position of list item button and after I move the button to the position I want the emulator gives me an error.. So can anybody tell my why this code works fine:

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/messages_list_item"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:gravity="left|center"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" >

<Button
android:id="@+id/send_message_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/send" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/destination"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/message_text" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And if I move Button element to the bottom like this:

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/messages_list_item"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:gravity="left|center"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/destination"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/message_text" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>

<Button
android:id="@+id/send_message_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:text="@string/send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

It does not launch on the emulator?

Here is my activity view:

layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/base_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/messages_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Please, explain what do you want exactly and why ?

Comment: Post your logcat showing the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be see the `list_item.xml` file. You wrote the code of Button to times and close the `</LinearLayout>` one times more. I think it give error in `list_item.xml`

.

Comment: I edited that now. It was my mistake when I was copying. In my code it is like it is now.

Comment: Please, explain what do you want exactly and why ?

Comment: I want to move button from left side to right. And after i make that changes there comes error in emulator. And i don't know why that error comes. I make just that simple change from first list_item.xml to secont list_item.xml

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/messages_list_item"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:gravity="left|center"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/destination"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/message_text" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>

<Button
android:id="@+id/send_message_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/send" />

</LinearLayout>

<Button
android:id="@+id/send_message_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:text="@string/send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In the second xml, I think you doubled the 6 last lines... So you close too much LinearLayout.

Comment: Now, you close two times the LinearLayout... ;)

Comment: Yes because there are two LinearLayouts

Comment: Ok, you corrected it to... You closed three times a LinearLayout, before... Now it doesn't work either? Could you paste the logcat of your error, please?